# Good book on asymptotics and especially equivalence

Tags: real-analysis, asymptotics

I'm trying to deepen my knowledge of asymptotic analysis and I find very few resources must of them just state the definition and theorems.

I'm especially looking to understand this definition more clearly $$ f(x)=g(x)(1+o(1))$$ sometines writen like this: $$u_n=(1+\epsilon(n))v_n$$

Answer (score 3):

A classic is
"Asymptotic Methods in Analysis"
by N. G. de Bruijn.

Hard copy about \$15,
Kindle version \$10,
both from Dover
(in Amazon).

Answer (score 2):

A short exposition with examples is Hildebrand's ["A Short Course on Asymptotics"](https://faculty.math.illinois.edu/%7Ehildebr/lecture-notes/asymptotics.pdf). There are more extensive works around, but I like this one as it is reasonably rigorous while short and readable. Be careful, the notations are sometimes defined slightly (or blatantly) differently (Hildebrand's seem to be the current consensus, in Computer Science it is often also understood that the functions are positive throughout and the interest is in $n \to \infty$).

Comment: Great thanks, really wonder why it's so hard to find stuff like this in English! Mush easier in my other language
Edit: I gave it a look, the PDF is nice but doesn't tackle the case where one function isn't strictly positive after a certain point